# javascript google maps Geocoder caller function ends up before callee function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocode

I work on geocoder on javascript. I have a function named codeAddress which takes address and gives coordinates correctly. However when i call this function in another function i can't get correct results because caller function ends up before codeAddress function.
Here is my code:

```
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var lokasyon ={ id:0,lat:0,lng:0 };
    var lokasyonlar=[];
    function codeAddress(adres, id) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': adres }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lokasyon.id = id;
                lokasyon.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                lokasyon.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                lokasyonlar.push(lokasyon);
                alert("codeAddress");
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
    function trial2() {
        codeAddress("1.ADA SOKAK, ADALET, OSMANGAZİ, Bursa", 12);
        alert("trial2");
    }
    window.onload = trial2;
```

when i run this code, firstly "trial2" is shown and then "codeAddress". What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 1):

Because geocoder.geocode() method asks to Google server, and it will take a few second.
It means geocode() method is asynchronous, and alert("trial2") is faster than callback.

If you want to execute the code 'alert("trial2")' after the callback, you need to change like this:

```
function codeAddress(adres, id, callback) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': adres }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lokasyon.id = id;
            lokasyon.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lokasyon.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            lokasyonlar.push(lokasyon);
            alert("codeAddress");
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
        callback();
    });
}
function trial2() {
    codeAddress("1.ADA SOKAK, ADALET, OSMANGAZİ, Bursa", 12, function(){
      alert("trial2");
    });
}
```